# SQL Syntax error INET_ATON

Tags: php, mysql

I got following error message in my script after upgrading MySQL version.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '''),NOW(''),INET_ATON(123.231.110.114),'0','0')' at line 4

My code as given below:

```
'".$agef."','".$aget."','".$heightf."','".$heightt."',
'".$weightf."','".$weightt."','".$hdyfu."','".$picture[0]."',
'".$picture[1]."','".$picture[2]."','".horo($month, $day)."',
NOW(''),NOW(''),INET_ATON('".ip()."'),'".$cst."','0')") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

Please suggest me corrected code.

Comment: `NOW('')` huh? Those should read as just `NOW()`. It doesn't take an argument. RTM https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now

Comment: and `INET_ATON()` expects a quoted string

Comment: @RiggsFolly Not even 5 mins. I've left this `NOW()`. ;-)